# Prevent javascript from evaluating object property first

Tags: javascript

I am creating a game of chess and have this line of code:

```
void (!selectedPiece.moved && selectedPiece.moved = true);
```

What it does, is check if `selectedPiece.moved` is false, and if it is, continue and set `selectedPiece.moved` to true.

As @Klaycon said, it reads it like this:

```
void (!selectedPiece.moved && selectedPiece.moved) = true;
```

And that is when I get an invalid left-hand side assignment. I know I could replace it with an if statement but I was wondering if there was something else I could do to fix it.

Comment: To clarify, the problem is not JavaScript evaluating your properties as you write, it's simple order of operations. Currently it evaluates as if you wrote `(!selectedPiece.moved && selectedPiece.moved) = true`, hence the "invalid left-hand side assignment".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some parenthesis. The outer ones are not necessary.

```
void !selectedPiece.moved && (selectedPiece.moved = true);
```

An even shorter approach uses an logical OR without a logical NOT for the first part.

```
void selectedPiece.moved || (selectedPiece.moved = true);
```

But anyway, you could assign `true` without check, if the value is a boolean.

```
selectedPiece.moved = true;
```